# Error: Couldn't find preset "react" when installed using npm install --global babel-preset-react but works without global flag

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I installed Babel CLI (version 6) using `npm install --global babel-cli`. I then install react preset using `npm install --global babel-preset-react`.

I then setup the `.babelrc` file in the project directory to

```
{
    "presets": ["react"]
}
```

When I try to build a JSX file it fails with

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "react"
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:310:17)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:270:12)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:206:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:392:12)
    at File.initOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
    at new File (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
    at transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:53:22)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:62:12)
```

If I install the preset without --global flag (i.e. installs in node_modules/ folder locally) then the build works. How do i set up to get babel to work with a global preset?

Comment: I ran into this same error when trying to run babel from Python as a separate process. It worked properly on the console, so I did some minor debugging. I added console.log(dirname) to line 305 of options-manager.js and found that the current working directory had to be the project directory. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: What is the point to use presets global?

Comment: @CookieOfFortune - i dont think that being in project directory is necessary. i installed the module locally in some other folder and built the project from there. it works as long as the current working directory has the module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the absolute (or relative) path to the preset you are trying to use, e.g:

```
babel --presets /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-preset-react --watch jsx/ --out-dir js/
```

Comment: After re creating the VM and reinstalling libs with `sudo apt-get -y install nodejs-legacy npm` then `sudo npm install --global babel-cli` and then `sudo npm install --global babel-preset-react`. The solution works. **Pls note that you have to remove the .babelrc file for it to work.** @Petar - can you edit your answer?

Comment: Worked for me as I'm using grunt. Now the transform is like: `['babelify',{
              presets: [__dirname+'/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015'],
            }]`

Answer (score 1):

## Optional Fix

You can do it this way. Write these lines in your prompt. Now the only thing is with global you might have to use the fix suggested above by @Petar
which is

```
babel --presets /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-preset-react --watch jsx/ --out-dir js/
```

but this one does all you need.

```
npm i babel-cli babel-preset-react 

babel --presets react jsx/ --watch --out-dir js/
```

and Then optionally add a .gitignore file in your github repo with content = node_modules/
now run your jsx transformation with the same command.